# How can I convert an array of objects in JS into a string concatenation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the input from the req.body like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Test_1",
        "Level 1": "Story_1",
        "Level 2": "Story_1.1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Test_2",
        "Level 1": "Story_2",
        "Level 2": "Story_2.2"
    }
]
```

I want to concatenate the objects along with a delimiter, in my case the delimiter is '>'.
So, the desired output for each object is:

```
 >Test_1>Story_1>Story_1.1>
>Test_2>Story_2>Story_2.2>
```

Comment: Anything you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Object.values](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/object/values) to get all the values in order, and [array.join](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/join) to merge them all

```js
const data = [
  {
    Name: 'Test_1',
    'Level 1': 'Story_1',
    'Level 2': 'Story_1.1'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Test_2',
    'Level 1': 'Story_2',
    'Level 2': 'Story_2.2'
  }
]

const strings = data.map(toStringLine.bind(null, '>'))
console.log(strings)

function toStringLine (char, obj) {
  return `${char}${Object.values(obj).join(char)}${char}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array of keys and maintain the order of the wanted result for mapping.

```js
const
    data = [{ "Name": "Test_1", "Level 1": "Story_1", "Level 2": "Story_1.1" }, { "Name": "Test_2", "Level 1": "Story_2", "Level 2": "Story_2.2" }],
    keys = ["Name", "Level 1", "Level 2"],
    result = data.map(o => `>${keys.map(k => o[k]).join('>')}>`);

console.log(result);
```